# Can't seem to get wp_localize_script to work

Tags: ajax, wp-localize-script

This is my code:

```
wp_enqueue_script('ms_ajax_localized');

wp_localize_script( 'ms_ajax_localized', 'MS_Ajax', array(
    'ajaxurl'       => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'nextNonce'     => wp_create_nonce( 'myajax-next-nonce' ))
);
```

I popped it into my `functions.php`

Bashing my head against the wall. I've used wp_localize_script before and I'm just blind to what is wrong this time.

When I load the page I can't find the script tag in the source anywhere...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested that code like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'MS_Ajax', array(
    'ajaxurl'       => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'nextNonce'     => wp_create_nonce( 'myajax-next-nonce' ))
);
```

And it works but throws a `Notice`. It should be hooked to `wp_enqueue_scripts` like:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_localize_script( 'jquery', 'MS_Ajax', array(
        'ajaxurl'       => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        'nextNonce'     => wp_create_nonce( 'myajax-next-nonce' ))
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_enqueue_scripts');
```

You have to have your script registered and enqueued correctly [before you use `wp_localize_script`.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) Since the code I tested, using the Core supplied `jquery` works, I have to assume that that is the problem. Your [script registration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script), which I don't see at all, or [script enqueueing](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) is going bad and thus `wp_localize_script` script isn't working.

Comment: I had an unnecessary condition around my enqueue_script. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Tried your code but it doesn't seem to be working. I want to add some PHP vars to be used with JS without tying it to a specific script.. And nothing gets printed by your suggestion. Hm.

Comment: You have to tie it to a script. Not especially found of it but that is how `wp_localize_script` works.