# Injecting a javascript banner code right before & after wordpress navigation menu

Tags: plugins

I am trying to develop a plugin to inject a javascript banner code right before and after the wordpress navigation menu but I am unable to find any solution to this problem. Does anyone have any idea?

I cannot append to a Div ID either since every wordpress theme uses different div id and class for navigation menu.

Thanks

Edit: 
Banner code is adsense javascript code. Wordpress does have wp_nav_menu functionality and i want to inject javascript before and after wp_nav_menu.

Comment: What is a "banner code"? Answer with an [edit] please.

Comment: And there really is no "WordPress" menu (unless you mean the Admin bar). The theme creates the menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Core menu system, which was not mentioned in the initial version of the question, does not have any "before" and "after" hooks that I can find. You could create a custom Walker that could include those hooks but it is going to be a theme problem, either way.

If that is not satisfactory, you will need to alter the DOM with Javascript. I don't know if that is even possible/viable for the code you want to include but if that is an option you need to hook code to `wp_enqueue_scripts` something like this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/128250/21376.

You can use `wp_localize_script()` to write data to the page that your script can use. For example: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/92184/21376.

Comment: I cannot use external script js file here since I am pulling script code from wordpress db using "get_option()"

Comment: It is nonetheless correct that you would need to use Javascript to alter the DOM. See the edit.